# Como obtener router.query al montarse un componente?

Tags: router, nextjs

Tengo una pagina que funciona como un buscador, `/rentals`. Tiene en su interior un componente para seleccionar dos fechas y buscar.  Las selecciono, le doy clic al boton y me redirige a otra pagina donde tengo resultados, algo asi: `/search?fecha1=xxxx&fecha2=xxxx`

En esta nueva pagina, `/search`, ademas de los resultados, tambien estoy renderizando nuevamente el componente que tiene los desplegables para elegir fechas, y el boton de busqueda. Para poder realizar otra busqueda dentro de la misma pagina.

Quiero hacer dos cosas:

1- Que al cargarse `/search`, poder leer `router.query` (donde deberia tener `.fecha1` y `.fecha2`), y se seteen automaticamente en los select.

2- Si el usuario accede por teclado a `/search`, quiero setear dos fechas por defecto y realizar la busqueda. Es decir, el usuario ingresa a `/search` y automaticamente debe ser redirigido a `/search?fecha1=fechapordefecto1&fecha2=fechapordefecto2`

En mi pagina `/search` intento lo algo como esto:

```
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  if(router.query && router.query.fecha1 && router.query.fecha2){
    // hay fechas en la ruta, deberia setearlas en el buscador
  } else {
    // No hay fechas en la ruta, entonces hago un router.push(`/search?fecha1=${fechapordefecto1}&fecha2=${fechapordefecto2}`) 
  }
}, []);
```

Pero como se darán cuenta, lo que sucede con esta lógica es que siempre va a entrar al `else`, ya que en el primer instante detecta `router.query` como un objeto vacío.

Podria usar `[router.query]` como dependencia, pero el problema que tengo es el mismo. Si bien luego de un instante lo detecta, antes imprime un objeto vacio, por lo que tambien entraría en el `else`

Hay alguna forma de detectar el objeto `query` del `router` practicamente antes de que el componente empiece a montarse?

Edit:

La pagina `/search` solo tiene esto, utiliza al componente `WinterSearch` para renderizar:

```
import WinterSearch from "@/src/components/search/winter";

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const url = `${process.env.CW_BASE_URL}/search_winter-rentals` || null;

  return {
    props: {
      pageData: {
        canonicalUrl: url,
      },
      isSearchPage: true,
      isWinterSearch: true,
    },
    revalidate: parseInt(process.env.STATIC_REGEN_TIME || "240", 10),
  };
};

export default WinterSearch;
```

Le consuté a ChatGPT y me dice que use `getInitialProps`, pero no se puede en mi caso, ya que antes estoy usando `getStaticProps` por lo que recibo el error

> Error: You can not use getInitialProps with getStaticProps. To use SSG, please remove your getInitialProps /search

Comment: Lo que hice fue reemplazar  ``getStaticProps`` por  ``getServerSideProps``, de esta manera puedo obtener ``{query}``. Tuve que eliminar ``revalidate`` y no estoy seguro de cómo voy a afectar el rendimiento con este cambio.